# Create react component library and import into a next js application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, antd, vite

I am creating a component library with react js, vite tailwindcss and antd. Components work perfectly when running the project locally, or running in the storybook. However, when importing into another nextjs application, the components appear without styling. This is my package.json configuration:

```
Package.json

"type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "files": [
    "/dist",
    "/src"
  ],
```

vite.config.js

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'node:path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'lw-ds',
      fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```

[This is the structure in node_modules after importing into another application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNv0P.png)

I've tried pretty much everything to get it to work. If I create a components folder in my application and copy the files to this folder, even if I'm importing from my library directly the styling works

Answer (score 0):

you need to import in your next app, in _app.tsx or jsx

```
import "your-library/dist/style.css";
```